# On the Poisson integral formula for the upper half plane

Tags: complex-analysis

I was trying to derive the Poisson formula for the upper half plane. However, I got stuck and found this [Derive the Poisson Formula for a bounded C-harmonic function in the upper half-plane.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/420178/derive-the-poisson-formula-for-a-bounded-c-harmonic-function-in-the-upper-half-p) 
Now I am not able to prove the inequality $|(\zeta - z)(\zeta -\overline{z})|>\frac{1}{2}R^2$ which is required as per the answer by @mrf. I think its simple and straightforward but somehow I am missing out something. It will be really helpful if someone can provide me the details. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $z$ is fixed in the upper half-plane and $\zeta$ is on the disk of radius $R$ so $|\zeta-z|^2 \ge (R-|z|)^2$, that's all you need.For $R$ large enough $(R-|z|)^2\ge \frac{R^2}{2} $

Comment: @reuns Thanks. I got it.