# Condition to hold $u(z) \leq \dfrac{y}{\pi}\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\dfrac{u(t)}{(x-t)^2 + y^2}dt$ for subharmonic functions

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, reference-request

I recently read a paper where it mentioned an inequality, called "Poisson representation" for subharmonic functions. From the context in the paper I guess that:

if $u(z)$ is a subharmonic function on the upper half-plane $\mathbb{C}_{+} = \{z=x +iy\in\mathbb{C}: y >0\}$ then under some further conditions on the growth of $u$, we will have the inequality
$$u(z) \leq \dfrac{y}{\pi}\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\dfrac{u(t)}{(x-t)^2 + y^2}dt,\quad \forall z = x+i y \in \mathbb{C}_{+}. $$

I would like to study more about this result. Could someone give me a precise statement of this inequality? Or a reference would be very helpful.

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/420178/42969.

Comment: I did read this but it's not clear to me what statement shoud follow.